# Reverse the Index Column in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a set of data of column fetching from API to that i've added an index column which start from 1+incrementing order. For ex I have a Index Column 1-50 if i tried to reverse it or sort it means the other columns are also getting reversed or sorted. But i need the Index column only to get reversed or sorted
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiwcF.png)

In the above image i've to reverse only the Race not the other three columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powerquery, to reverse an index column

```
#"ReverseIndex" = Table.TransformColumns(#"PriorStepName",{{"Index", each Table.RowCount(#"PriorStepName")-_, Int64.Type}})
```

Or just use an index that counts in reverse to start with:

```
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"PriorStepName", "Index", Table.RowCount(#"PriorStepName"), -1, Int64.Type)
```

Comment: Ok Sir, alright

Answer (score 0):

1. Select only index column which you need to sort without other columns
2. do sort
3. select "Continue with the current selection"
4. click Sort button
   [sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6kxn.png)